# Using a table field as part of an identifier

Tags: sql-server

I have coded the following table and I would like to use the the text that will be entered into the `YearID` to add to a prefixed `'YEAR'` in the `CAST()`.

For example if someone named the `year` `2` then the `YearID` field would be populated as `'YEAR2'`. Currently it will just apply the next number in the sequence after `YEAR` e.g. `YEAR55` etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Year(
    GroupID             INT IDENTITY (10000, 1)  NOT NULL,
    YearID              VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'YEAR' + 
                            CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR non_identity_incrementer AS VARCHAR(10)),
    Year                NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    DateTimeModified    DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    Status              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (GroupID) 
);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is something supported by the `DEFAULT` system, though you could do it with an INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computed column might be the solution:

```
CREATE TABLE [Year] (
    GroupID             INT IDENTITY (10000, 1)  NOT NULL,
    YearID              AS 'YEAR' + [Year],
    [Year]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    DateTimeModified    DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    Status              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (GroupID) 
);
```

When you `INSERT` a row, the `YearID` would be equal to `'Year' + [Year]`:

```
INSERT INTO [Year]([Year], Status) VALUES ('2', 'Complete')
SELECT * FROM [Year]
```

Result:

```
GroupID     YearID     Year      DateTimeModified        Status
----------- ---------- --------- ----------------------- ------------
10000       YEAR2      2         2015-08-17 07:02:49.837 Complete
```

---

Note that the computed column is recalculated every time it is used in a query, unless you make it `PERSISTED`. Making the computed column `PERSISTED` means that it is physically stored in the table. Read [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trigger, like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER year_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON Year FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

set NEW.YearID = concat('YEAR', NEW.Year);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

It will run after insertion on Year, setting `YearID` based on `Year`.